# What is the intended way to achieve two-way binding with the Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here is the scenario I'm trying to achieve with the Kendo UI grid:

1. Retrieve some persisted data via jquery, restangular, or whatever.
2. Bind the grid to the data.
3. Edit the data in the grid.
4. Add a new row to the grid.
5. Click some "Save" button and send the updated data back to the server.

Based on what I've read, when using the Kendo UI grid you have to wrap the array you supply for the data source in order for the grid to update the original model.  The grid's built-in commands, however, don't seem to operate correctly when you do this.  As shown in the following example, upon clicking 'Edit' on a row, you can't then click 'Update' or 'Cancel'.  It just gets stuck.  If you don't wrap it with an array, the existing records are updated fine, but then you don't get new records added to the origin array.

http://dojo.telerik.com/aTIba

The faulty behavior seems to have something to do with the fact that a uid is placed on the records by wrapping them with an ObservableArray.  Oddly, passing in an empty array (as you might do for an Add vs and Edit dialog), the buttons work correctly and the underlying datasource is modified.

So, what's wrong with this configuration?

**Update**

The original example displayed the id field as one of the columns which was proving to be a distraction from the real issue for several people I've received feedback from, so I've removed it.  I also add the ability to add a new row and added output to see the contents of the original data source.

Comment: At present, I'm not sure that my usage scenario isn't the intended way to do it, but it appears there may be a bug with the Kendo UI grid that's causing the behavior described.  For now, my work around is to retrieve the data from the grid at the point I'm saving the data via a call to vm.grid.dataSource.data();  Thanks to my co-worker [Joe Stetzer](https://www.linkedin.com/in/joestetz) for providing the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you un-wrap the ObservableArray and use a normal array instead, it seems to work.

```
  var sourceData = [
    { id:1, text: "Foo" },
    { id:2, text: "Bar" },
    { id:3, text: "Baz" }
  ];
```

It's been a while since I poked into the Kendo internals, but if I remember correctly, when you pass an array to `new DataSource` it will automatically wrap the array into observables.

If you use the plain array shown above then edit a field in the table, you can see the changed objects with `window.sourceData[0].text`

---

Additional note; since you have the `id` for the DataSource set to the `id` property, strange things happen if you edit that column in the table. IDs should be immutable. For example if you edit the 1st row with `id=1` and change the ID to `3`, then Kendo DataSource will go get the item with ID=3 (the 3rd row) and change the text from "Baz" to "Foo". In other words, Kendo finds the item to change by looking up its ID, not by tracking the index in the array.

Comment: I've updated my example to more fully demonstrate the problems I'm seeing.  If you don't wrap the source array in an ObservableArray, the initial records work fine, but you won't get new records added.  As far as kendo wrapping the array for you, that may very well be true, but however it's doing it, the original datasource doesn't end up with new items in the array.  Concerning the id, I removed the column for that as it was proving to be a distraction from the real issues.

Comment: Ah, interesting. For me when I use the ObservableArray, New and Edit/Save work fine, but Edit/Cancel causes problems... sometimes... sometimes if you edit/save one record first then edit/cancel works again. Seems inconsistent. I suspect this might just be a bug that you should send to Telerik.